# Network discovery using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Do you have any idea how to find router in network using Kibana?

First I would like find behavior of 1 router then all routers in network..

Thank you for opinion or link where I can find information how set up queries for Elasticsearch in Kibana.

Comment: Why do you need kibana to find router in the network ?

Comment: Because : When someone add router to my network I should get syslog, And that syslog should be different from others logs..